# Silent Hill 4 crashes when I pick any item, I'm using the Widescreen fix

Tags: silent-hill-4

I downloaded [this fix](https://github.com/ThirteenAG/WidescreenFixesPack/releases/tag/sh4) for Silent Hill 4 on PC. The fix improved the frame rate during cut scenes and overall, but when I pick any item the game automatically crashes.

This is the configuration I have on the script file:

```
[MAIN]
ResX = 1366
ResY = 768
Fix2D = 1 // Corrects menus and FMVs, but disables some visual effects.
FixFOV = 1
DisableCutsceneBorders = 1 // Removes cutscene letterboxing.
IncreaseBackgroundRes = 1 // Pause background will render at native resolution.
CutsceneFrameRateFix = 1 // Cutscenes will not be limited to 15fps.
DisableCheckSpec = 1 // Bypasses hardware check.

[MISC]
DisableRegistryDependency = 1 // Allows the game to run without the registry data.
DisableSafeMode = 1 // Prevents the game from using default settings after closing the game.
SkipIntro = 1
BrightnessFix = 1 // Adjusts default settings to match the PS2 version.
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I changed the name of the question because the crashes happen while picking any item, not just notes.

Comment: Try removing the "Fix 2d" option. It seems that some things do not work well on SH4 when that is on

Comment: @Moacir didn't work, still crashes while picking anything.

Comment: I suppose you could open an issue on [Github](https://github.com/ThirteenAG/WidescreenFixesPack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the script file I used to fix the issue:

```
[MAIN]
ResX = 0
ResY = 0
Fix2D = 0 // Corrects menus and FMVs, but disables some visual effects.
FixFOV = 1
DisableCutsceneBorders = 1 // Removes cutscene letterboxing.
IncreaseBackgroundRes = 1 // Pause background will render at native resolution.
CutsceneFrameRateFix = 1 // Cutscenes will not be limited to 15fps.
DisableCheckSpec = 1 // Bypasses hardware check.

[MISC]
DisableRegistryDependency = 0 // Allows the game to run without the registry data.
DisableSafeMode = 1 // Prevents the game from using default settings after closing the game.
SkipIntro = 0
BrightnessFix = 1 // Adjusts default settings to match the PS2 version.
```

Comment: Is this the same as the [downloadable file linked to in your other answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/354854/4797)? If yes, just edit this into your older answer, and delete this answer instead. Duplicate answers are deleted here.

Comment: This worked for me, I copied your configuration into my .ini file and now I can play without issues, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
[MAIN]
ResX = 0
ResY = 0
Fix2D = 1 // Corrects menus and FMVs, but disables some visual effects.
FixFOV = 1
DisableCutsceneBorders = 1 // Removes cutscene letterboxing.
IncreaseBackgroundRes = 1 // Pause background will render at native resolution.
CutsceneFrameRateFix = 1 // Cutscenes will not be limited to 15fps.
DisableCheckSpec = 1 // Bypasses hardware check.

[MISC]
DisableRegistryDependency = 0 // Allows the game to run without the registry data.
DisableSafeMode = 0 // Prevents the game from using default settings after closing the game.
SkipIntro = 0
BrightnessFix = 0 // Adjusts default settings to match the PS2 version.
```

Right, with a little research, I've solved the problem (for me). The above is my settings and I've managed to bypass all of the problems.

If that doesn't work, check out what this guy did. (which basically got me experimenting until I found the solution that worked for me.)

https://silenthillcommunity.com/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=438372

Comment: This is different from what Foxhound says worked for him in his answer. Does his configuration work? If so, why bother rehashing it. If not, please tell us.

Comment: no his is different. he took the 1s from the backgroiund res and the fix2d, but i was still having the issues trying that. I actually discovered from fixing mine that if you just add the intro (i.e put a 1 instead of a 0 in the skipintro text) it'll work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I've fixed it using this [Silent Hill 4 Fix](http://www.mediafire.com/file/fq4420mwdyjx5aa/Silent_Hill_4_Fix_Bordes%252C_fps_y_crasheos.rar/file).

Comment: Hi Foxhound, can you explain what the file does, where you found it, and offer an alternative link that is not as suspicious?